# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'idzwierzatka' cannot be null

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I have problem with SonataAdminBundle after join table.
Problem is:

An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO zdjecia (idzwierzatka, imageName, path) VALUES (?, ?, ?)' with params [null, "51ac56544e478.jpeg", null]:
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'idzwierzatka' cannot be null

I don't know, what to do.
My entity( I must put into one file,becouse of my low reputation) :

https://github.com/dduuch/problem/tree/master/src/Multimedia/AccountBundle/Entity 
(see Zdjecia and Zwierzeta)

And Sonata Admin's files( I must put into one file,becouse of my low reputation):
https://github.com/dduuch/problem/tree/master/src/Multimedia/StronaBundle/Admin 
(see Zdjecia and Zwierzeta)

If i change in Entity Zdjecia with nullable:

```
/**
 * @var integer $idzwierzatka
 * @ORM\Column(name="idzwierzatka", type="integer", length=10, nullable=true )
 */
protected $idzwierzatka;
```

Sonata didn't add my idzwierzatka to the database.

Sorry,for my bad english.
I'm beginner in Symfony2. Please say me like a little child what i have wrong ;)

Best regards

UPDATE

I have solved this.
In ZdjeciaAdmin I have in "idzwierzatka" requirer => true. Last time when I have comment this, I have forget update database scheme. 
Now it works.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sonata isn't responsible for managing entities at the database level, Doctrine is. Try running the following command to update your entities:

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

Comment: Yes, that modify my schema, but still don't add "idzwierzatka"  to database, when I upload any file.

They add: Idzdjecia, Image(path). Idzwierzatka is null )